# Running a query with lots of INSERT statement and one SELECT statement in the wrong order

Tags: c++, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, odbc

I would like to INSERT lots of rows in a table. I send my values as an array to a parameterized INSERT Query with ODBC in C++ like this:

```
INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(?,?)  select wert1  from information1 WHERE Wert2=9"
```

as you see I would like to run a select statement after INSERTs.

This code is able to insert rows in the table, but the result of select statement is wrong (The rsualt should be **d**). I have this expectation that something like this runs in the database:

```
INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(a,4)
INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(b,3)
INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(c,17)
INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(d,9)
INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(e,5)
INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(f,45)
INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(g,6)
INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(h,4)
INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(i,2)
SELECT Wert1 FROM information1 WHERE Wert2=9
```

but what actually happend is:

```
   INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(a,4)
    SELECT Wert1 FROM information1 WHERE Wert2=9
    INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(b,3)
    INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(c,17)
    INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(d,9)
    INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(e,5)
    INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(f,45)
    INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(g,6)
    INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(h,4)
    INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(i,2)
```

hence it returns nothing (wrong result for me). Could someone explain me why the wrong order of statements are run in database? and how should I change my code to have the correct order?

Here you can find my whole code:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<tchar.h>

#include <sql.h> 
#include <sqlext.h> 
#include<sqltypes.h>


//#include<odbcss.h>
//#include<odbcinst.h>

#include<exception>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

#include <conio.h>


#include "Debug\sqlncli.h";

void HandleDiagnosticRecord (SQLHANDLE      hHandle,    
                             SQLSMALLINT    hType,  
                             RETCODE        RetCode)
{
    SQLSMALLINT iRec = 0;
    SQLINTEGER  iError;
    WCHAR       wszMessage[1000];
    WCHAR       wszState[SQL_SQLSTATE_SIZE+1];


    if (RetCode == SQL_INVALID_HANDLE)
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"Invalid handle!\n");
        return;
    }

    while (SQLGetDiagRec(hType,
                         hHandle,
                         ++iRec,
                         wszState,
                         &iError,
                         wszMessage,
                         (SQLSMALLINT)(sizeof(wszMessage) / sizeof(WCHAR)),
                         (SQLSMALLINT *)NULL) == SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
        // Hide data truncated..
        if (wcsncmp(wszState, L"01004", 5))
        {
            fwprintf(stderr, L"[%5.5s] %s (%d)\n", wszState, wszMessage, iError);
        }
    }


}

#define TRYODBC(h, ht, x)   {   RETCODE rc = x;\
                             if (rc != SQL_SUCCESS) \
                                { \
                                    HandleDiagnosticRecord (h, ht, rc); \
                                } \
                                if (rc == SQL_ERROR) \
                                { \
                                    fwprintf(stderr, L"Error in " L#x L"\n"); \
                                    Sleep(30000); \
                                }  \
                            }


void extract_error(
      char *fn,
      SQLHANDLE handle,
      SQLSMALLINT type)
  {
    SQLINTEGER i = 0;
    SQLINTEGER native;
    SQLWCHAR state[ 7 ];
    SQLWCHAR text[256];
    SQLSMALLINT len;
    SQLRETURN ret;
    fprintf(stderr,
            "\n"
            "The driver reported the following diagnostics whilst running "
            "%s\n\n",
            fn);

    do
    {
      ret = SQLGetDiagRec(type, handle, ++i, state, &native, text,
      sizeof(text), &len );
      if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
      printf("%s:%ld:%ld:%s\n", state, i, native, text);
    }
    while( ret == SQL_SUCCESS );
  }


    int main()
    {
        SQLHENV henv=SQL_NULL_HENV;
        SQLHDBC hdbc=SQL_NULL_HDBC;
        SQLHSTMT hstmt=SQL_NULL_HSTMT;
        RETCODE rc;

        SQLTCHAR Statement[] = _T("INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(?,?)  select count(*) as a from information1 ") ;
        SQLTCHAR sqlStatementOUT[255];
        SQLINTEGER lenStatementOUT=0;
        memset(sqlStatementOUT,' ',255);



   SQLWCHAR dsn[30] = L"mssqltest"; //Name DNS
   SQLWCHAR user[10] = L"di_test";
   SQLWCHAR pass[10] = L"di_test";

   SQLCHAR retValFName[256];
   SQLCHAR retValLName[256];
   SQLINTEGER cbLName,cbFName;
   SQLLEN cName=0;

   SQLCHAR *TVPTableName=(SQLCHAR *) "TableTVP";

    #define PARAM_ARRAY_SIZE 9
    #define STRING_SIZE 20

   SQLCHAR     Arrayname1[PARAM_ARRAY_SIZE][STRING_SIZE] = {"4","3","17","9","5","45","6","4","2"};
SQLCHAR     Arrayname2[PARAM_ARRAY_SIZE][STRING_SIZE] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"};

    SQLLEN cbTVPTableNAme=10;
    SQLLEN cbArraycode[10],cbArrayname[10];
    SQLLEN  lTVPRowsUsed;


   rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);   

   rc= SQLSetEnvAttr(henv,SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,(void *) SQL_OV_ODBC3,0);

   rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc); 

   rc = SQLConnectW(hdbc, (SQLWCHAR *)dsn, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR *) user, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR *) pass, SQL_NTS); // from this line rc=-1

   rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT,hdbc,&hstmt);


   rc = SQLSetStmtAttr (hstmt, SQL_ATTR_PARAM_BIND_TYPE, SQL_PARAM_BIND_BY_COLUMN, 0);
   SQLUSMALLINT Param_status_array[PARAM_ARRAY_SIZE];
   SQLULEN ParamsProcessed;
   rc=SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt,SQL_ATTR_PARAMSET_SIZE,(SQLPOINTER*) PARAM_ARRAY_SIZE, 0);
   rc=SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt,SQL_ATTR_PARAM_STATUS_PTR,Param_status_array,0);
   rc=SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt,SQL_ATTR_PARAMS_PROCESSED_PTR,&ParamsProcessed,0);

   SQLUSMALLINT newsize=0;


   rc=SQLBindParameter(hstmt,1,SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, STRING_SIZE, 0, Arrayname1, STRING_SIZE,0);
   rc=SQLBindParameter(hstmt,2,SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, STRING_SIZE, 0, Arrayname2, STRING_SIZE,0);

   rc = SQLPrepare(hstmt, (SQLTCHAR *)Statement, SQL_NTS);
   rc=SQLGetStmtAttr(hstmt,SQL_ATTR_PARAMSET_SIZE,&newsize,4,NULL);
   newsize=0;

   rc = SQLExecute(hstmt);
   rc=SQLGetStmtAttr(hstmt,SQL_ATTR_PARAMSET_SIZE,&newsize,4,NULL);


   if(rc==SQL_SUCCESS)
   {
       SQLSMALLINT sNumResults;
       SQLNumResultCols(hstmt,&sNumResults);
       SQLBindCol(hstmt,
                    1,
                    SQL_C_TCHAR,
                    (SQLPOINTER) retValFName,
                    100,
                   0);
   while(true)
        {
          rc=SQLFetch(hstmt);

          if(rc==SQL_SUCCESS || rc==SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
          {

             SQLGetData(hstmt,1,SQL_C_CHAR,retValFName,256, &cbLName);
             std::cout << retValFName <<"   "<< std::endl;

          }
          else
          {
              break;
          }
        }
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not put all sql instruction insert on the same line separate with ; ?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(?,?) ; select wert1  from information1 WHERE Wert2=9"`

Comment: yup, you can add all your insert before

Comment: I have tested it, not working. result is the same as before

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(?,?)  Performs a SINGLE RECORD INSERT.  Not a bulk insert.
So when you excecute

```
INSERT INTO information1(Wert1,Wert2) VALUES(?,?)  select count(*) as a from information1
```

It performs a single insert and then the select.
Separate the two sql commands.  Perform the insert for the array, and then separately the select.

Comment: Thanks @Amir, It was my idea. Is it possible to do such a task in one batch. I don't like to do this job in two separate batchs

Comment: You can create a string that is a list of inserts for all of the array, and in the end place a select command.  It means generating the entire sql commands batch, and then executing it as is in one go.  But then you're not really utilizing the parameterisation and going into dynamic sqls. And it's usually better to refrain from that.

Comment: Sorry! I don't get exactly what you mean

Comment: Since you're working with sql-server, you can create a database procedure that receives a table type parameter.  Execute the procedure with all of the data you want inserted.  And then the procedure can also return result sets with the counters/data you want.

Comment: Ah, Ok. the problem is, that I have very stength limitation. I may not use SP . Actually my aim is to use Table valued parameter. As I know If I want to populate the TVP and then make a query on it, I should do all this in one batch.